# AOSP Build - syscall ERROR

Tags: android, system-calls, android-source

I am trying to build on an OS X (El Capitan), and this is the error I get:

> system/core/libcutils/threads.c:38:10: error: 'syscall' is deprecated:
>   first deprecated in OS X 10.12 - syscall(2) is unsupported; please
>   switch to a supported interface. For SYS_kdebug_trace use
>   kdebug_signpost(). [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]   return
>   syscall(SYS_thread_selfid);
>            ^ >/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:733:6:
>
> note: 'syscall' has been explicitly marked deprecated here

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I fixed it:

1. Download earlier Mac OSX SDK(10.11 worked for me) from
   https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/releases
2. Unzip and copy to 
   /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs

Comment: Worked for me with SDK 10.10